# Removing the panel that appears on the right hand side of OpenERP main page

Tags: python, odoo

How can we remove the panel that appears on right hand side of openERP's main page ,which shows ACTIONS ,LINKS,OTHER OPTIONS.From which file in openERP web server can we remove that.

Thanks,
Sameer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

serch for main_sidebar in web/addons/openerp/controllers/templates/form.mako

you can hide the toolbar using this css file:
web/addons/openerp/static/css/screen.cs