# Removing Database name and username from top Left hand side corner.

Tags: python, odoo

How can we remove the database name and username that appears on top left hand side corner in openERP window after openERP logo.In which file do we need to make changes to remove that.

Thanks,
Sameer

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to find the id of a `<div>` that you want to hide. Then search the source code for that id so you can use the same CSS technique that [enlightx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148821/removing-the-panel-that-appears-on-the-right-hand-side-of-openerp-main-page/8149572#8149572) answered for your other question.

Comment: By the way, @Sameer, if enlightx's answer was helpful, you should accept it by clicking on the big check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the `openerp-web` module. The location depends on your particular configuration. The relevant code can be found in the file `addons/web/static/src/xml/base.xml`. Search for `header_title` and edit the contents of the h1 tag of that class.